# Is there a difference in efficiency between these scripts?

Tags: javascript, performance

Theoretical case. The **function `init ()` may not always be called on the page**. What I want to know is if there is a difference from a speed/efficiency point of view between the two scripts? Will the fact that `Class` is a singleton make a difference to loading speed/amount of processing?

Script 1:

```
// Class is a singleton.
var Class =
{
    myFunctionOne : function ()
    {
    }

    myFunctionTwo: function ()
    {
    }
}

function init ()
{
    //Do some fancy stuff

    Class.myFunctionOne();
    Class.myFunctionTwo();
}
```

Script 2:

```
function Class ()
{
    this.myFunctionOne = function ()
    {
    }

    this.myFunctionTwo = function ()
    {
    }
}

function init ()
{
    var myClass = new Class();

    //Do some fancy stuff

    myClass.myFunctionOne();
    myClass.myFunctionTwo();
}
```

Comment: You could test it at [jsperf](http://www.jsperf.com)

Comment: I think this should be posted at Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Like most other performance questions... it likely depends on the implementation. Test it if you're curious.

Comment: the difference in performance is probably not important enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes, your second script has a performance advantage when `init()` is *not* being called on the page.  Here's why.

In your first example, the object literal will be parsed each time the page is loaded:

```
var Class =
{
    myFunctionOne : function () { ... }
}
```

The `Class` object will be built, each key set to a function object.  This overhead will be incurred regardless of whether these "methods" are ever actually called (though, it's possible certain JavaScript compilers may implement optimizations here such as "Just-In-Time compiling", so the actual perf gain may vary browser to browser)

In your second example:

```
function Class ()
{
    this.myFunctionOne = function () { ... }
}
```

The `myFunctionOne` line is being run each time `Class` is being called, in your case through the `new` operator.  This cost will be incurred each time `Class` is instantiated rather than once per page load.  However you've stated this class is using a singleton pattern so you'll only have one instance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about initial page load/processing time, why even have the code on the page. Load the JavaScript dynamically.

```
function init() {
    if(!document.getElementById("SingletonClass")) {
        var dynScript = document.createElement('script');
        dynScript.id = "SingletonClass";
        dynScript.type = "text/javascript";
        dynScript.src = "SingletonClass.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(dynScript);
    }
}
```

Or simply use the jQuery getScript function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/